# How change the background and foreground on the Office Ribbon

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm facing an issue using `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon`in my outlook add-in. I want to be able to implement custom colours onto the ribbon to match the theme of of the product. Here is a side by side comparison of something that i'd want to achieve, I'd also like to change the text to white.

[image]

[image]

From what I can see there is no properties that will allow me to change this from within the designer and I cannot find anyone who has attempted to change these colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do that - the color of the ribbon is determined by the Office theme.

Comment: How annoying would've been nice to change it, thank you for the quick response.